# Is there a set of existing unit tests for the various JS polyfills?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, polyfills

I am using several polyfills in IE11 and I wanted to use some unit tests to make sure the polyfills I am using are compliant with the spec.

For example, I have a polyfill for `Number.isNaN` from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN

Yes, that page includes a set of examples that I can use as unit tests to make sure the polyfill is working correctly. But does anyone know if there is a full set of unit tests already written that I can use to test all of the polyfills I am using?

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/test262?

Comment: Thanks for the link!!